# Getting a [550 5.1.1 Recipient not found] (Can't receive email) with CloudFlare

Tags: domain-name-system, email, smtp, mx-record, cloudflare

I'm having troubles with my email account. I'm using GoDaddy's Email service and the domains that are not connected to CloudFlare are operating just fine.

The problem comes in with the domains that I connect to CloudFlare, tried to get email from Twitter and Reddit with no success, then I've tried to send an email using my Gmail and got back this message:

> Technical details of permanent failure: Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain
>   mydomain.com by smtp.secureserver.net. [IP].
>
> The error that the other server returned was: 550 5.1.1
>    Recipient not found. 
>   http://x.co/irbounce

So I'm almost sure that my DNS MX setting are correct in CloudFlare since **www.dnswatch.info** says:

```
    MX  300 0 smtp.secureserver.net.
    MX  300 10 mailstore1.secureserver.net.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

So I've just fixed this error by looking at my GoDaddy hosted domains (the ones that are not using CloudFlare) and adding some CNAME's and changing my MX records from what I posted in the question to:

```
MX  300 0 smtp.asia.secureserver.net.
MX  300 10 mailstore1.asia.secureserver.net.
```

Basically I've just added "**.asia**" before "**secureserver.net**".